# Finding duplicates in a list/file. [Groovy/Java]

Tags: list, groovy, collections, duplicates, unique

I have an input file where each line is a special record. 
I would gladly work on the file level but might be a more convenient way to transfer the file into a list. (each object in the list = each row in the file)
In the input file, there can be several duplicate rows.
**The goal:** Split the given file/list into unique records and duplicate records, i.e., Records which are present multiple times, keep one occurrence and other duplicate parts store in a new list
I found an easy way how to remove duplicates but never found a way how to store them

```
File inputFile = new File("....")
inputFile.eachLine {    inputList.add(it)   } //fill the list
List inputList = [1,1,3,3,1,2,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,7,8,9,8,10]
inputList = inputList.unique() // remove duplicates
println inputList
// inputList = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The output should look like: Two lists/files with removed duplicates and duplicates itself

```
inputList = [1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] //only one ocurance of each line
listOfDuplicates = [1,1,1,3,3,2,7,8] //duplicates removed from original list
```

The output does not need to correspond with the initial order of items.
Thank you for help, Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply iterate over the list yourself:

```
def inputList = [1,1,3,3,1,2,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,7,8,9,8,10]

def uniques = []
def duplicates = []

inputList.each { uniques.contains(it) ? duplicates << it : uniques << it }

assert inputList.size() == uniques.size() + duplicates.size()
assert uniques == [1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] //only one ocurance of each line
assert duplicates == [1,3,1,2,3,1,7,8] //duplicates removed from original list

inputList = uniques // if desired
```

Comment: That's a clever approach, I feel ashamed I did not figure it out myself. Thanks Mike

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this,following is the simplest way

```
def list = [1,1,3,3,1,2,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,7,8,9,8,10]
        def unique=[]
        def duplicates=[]
        list.each {
            if(unique.contains(it))
                duplicates.add(it)
            else
                unique.add(it)

        }
        println list //[1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 8, 10]
        println unique //[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        println duplicates //[1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 8]
```

Hope this will helps you

Answer (score 1):

Something very straight-forward:

```
List inputList = [1,1,3,3,1,2,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,7,8,9,8,10] 
def uniques = [], duplicates = []

Iterator iter = inputList.iterator()
iter.each{
  iter.remove()
  inputList.contains( it ) ? ( duplicates << it ) : ( uniques << it )
}

assert [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10] == uniques
assert [1,1,3,3,1,2,7,8] == duplicates
```

Comment: I was sure it is something straightforward like that but I was not able to make it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

This code should solve the problem

```
 List listOfDuplicates = inputList.clone()
 listOfDuplicates.removeAll{
    listOfDuplicates.count(it) == 1
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If order of duplicates isn't important:

```
def list = [1,1,3,3,1,2,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,7,8,9,8,10]
def (unique, dups) = list.groupBy().values()*.with{ [it[0..0], tail()] }.transpose()*.sum()
assert unique == [1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
assert dups == [1,1,1,3,3,2,7,8]
```

Comment: Thanks for an interesting way how to do that, It is a bit hard to understand what is happening in the code, but I got it after all :) For my needs, this is too complicated and performance is significantly worse on high of records

Answer (score 0):

The more the merrier:

```
groovy:000> list.groupBy().values()*.tail().flatten()
===> [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 7, 8]
```

1. Group by identity (this is basically a "frequencies" function).
2. Take just the values
3. Clip the first element
4. Combine the lists